# Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js' on window10

Tags: node.js, npm

When I install any npm pakages such as: npm i lodash, npm i bcrypt, etc..., it errors like this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:153:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1. Rename the nodejs folder "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
2. Install node current stable version from https://nodejs.org/en/ again

Answer (score 3):

Version of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353545/error-cannot-find-module-lib-utils-unsupported-js-on-window10/61313136#57355365) adapted to OSX:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew reinstall node
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the folder `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\` and using your commands again. You may need to reinstall node.

Comment: i can't find npm inside Roaming folder. and when i reinstall node show "error 2330"

Comment: Tell me the output of `npm list -g`. You can use https://pastebin.com/ to share the result.

Comment: check my answer